# multiply the last two dimensions of the numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Lovely community,

I have to calculate the resolution of the image.
Following numpy array I have:

```
in: print(np.shape(imgs))
out: (760, 96, 84)
```

760: Number of pictures (num)

96: Height (h)

84: width (w)

My task is to multiply the second and the third dimension (result = h*w).

In this case it would return (num, result) as an numpy array.

but in my case it does need a lot of time.

```
arr = []

for i in range(len(imgs)):
    for k in range(len(imgs[i])):
        for j in range(len(imgs[i])):
            arr.append( np.multiply(imgs[k], imgs[j])  )
```

This way crashed my computer and going too long.

My next code would be

> ```
> arr = []
>
> for x in range(imgs.shape[0]):
>     for y in range(imgs.shape[1]):
>         arr.append(np.dot(x,y))
>
> print(np.shape(arr))
> ```

but it looks also wrong
Which way do you prefer in this complicated task?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you just trying to compute 96 times 84? "My task is to multiply the second and the third dimension (result = h*w)." sure sounds like you just want to multiply 96 by 84, but your code is doing nothing like that.

Comment: **Thanks for helping, I only get the task**

 """Turns an array (N, H, W), where N is the number of face images and H, W are height and width of the images into an (N, M) array where M=H*W is the image dimension. Args: imgs: (N, H, W) numpy array Returns: x: (N, M) numpy array" 

**or in general**

'implement the function vectorize_images that turns these images into vectors.'

Comment: So your task is to *reshape* this array, then.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `numpy.multiply()` function to element-wise multiply the height and width of each image more efficiently.

The code:

```
img_dims = np.shape(imgs)
img_prods = np.multiply(img_dims[1], img_dims[2])
```

Comment: "You can use the numpy.multiply() function to element-wise multiply the height and width of each image more efficiently." - but you're not doing anything elementwise, and even if you were, NumPy overloads the `*` operator to handle that anyway.

Comment: Have you tried the answer? the loop in the original post is causing the crash but in my code, I take advantage of Vectorization!

Comment: The answer works, technically, but it's not actually doing anything vectorized, and the use of `numpy.multiply` is completely superfluous. You're just multiplying two integers.

Comment: Anyway, I think it's the most efficient way to do it in Python.

Comment: It's not. [`*` massively outperforms `numpy.multiply` here](https://ideone.com/IpBGAq), since you're just multiplying two ints.